# Can we use Math.Round in <return > tag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

I have a progress bar whose value need to be calculated in reder part of react. Is there any chance i can do.Am not going with state or something.Just want to know is it possible

```
                   <div>
                        <div id="myProgress">
                          <div id="myBar">
                            Math.round(100 * (7 / 8})
                            %
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

My code looks like this but am getting error while doing this.Anyway i can do it in render. Here above equation am getting 7 after iterating JSON.

Any fiddle will be highly helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a JSX tag, but an expression. You will have to wrap it with curly brackets.

```
{Math.round(100 * (7 / 8))}%
```

**Note**: You are also missing a one round brace.